# Can't get my Application running after adding a tkinter interface

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Both my application's "motor" in Python 3.7.0 and my tkinter interface work without a hitch by themselves. The problem starts when I put the two together.
The following is a very simplified version of the beginning of my application, but it illustrates the basic problem:

```
from tkinter import *

request={} # this get more than just one piece of info.

def init():
        global request
        request['dir'] = text1.get()

# The real interface has:
# 2 Entry Widgets: file extention and keyword.
# 2 Buttons: Select Directory and Organize Files.
# this here is minimal interface
w = Tk()
text1 = StringVar()
Label(text=' Folder ').grid(row=0,column=0)
Entry(textvariable = text1).grid(row=0,column=1) # gets the input
Button(text='Organize', command=init).grid(row=4,column=0) 
w.mainloop()
# End of interface.

# ---------- Script starts here ----------------
# here I import several built-in and several personal modules like phps and helpers
# this modules have a whole bunch of functions. 
# ----------- VARIABLE ASSIGNMENT ------------- ##
# Here is where I need the interface and the script to connect.
# Path to the directory that will be looped through
BaseDir=request[0]+'/*' 
extRequired=request[1] # txt or docs, etc.
# a part of the basename e.g. my new filename keyword = "my new"
Keyword=request[2] 
# more vars ....

## ----------- SEARCH DIRECTORY ------------- ##

files=glob.glob(BaseDir)
for file in files:

    # EXTRACT file INFO
    info=phps.pathinfo(file) # phps is a module I made.
    # EXCLUDE Directories
    if not os.path.isdir(file):
        # SERACH for the Keyword
        Keyword_Exist = info['basename'].find(Keyword)
        # IS the KEYWORD in the String?
        if Keyword_Exist > -1 and info["ext"]==extRequired:
            RawfName = info["filename"][3:]
##  USE RawfName in the WRITE CONTENT TO FILE Section.

## ----------- GET FILE ------------- ##

            lines=open(file).readlines()
# etc ....
```

If you run the snippet, type a directory's name in the input box, and click on the button, nothing seems to happen, but it does. If you 
 close the interface, you'll see the user input needed to run the for loop appear on Python's shell, but the loop didn't run. 
Any ideas on how I can get this two separate scripts working together?

I basically want to keep the interface open, run the application which starts by looping through files according to the  user's input, have it do what it needs to, and then prestent a report to the user on a new window. The user can close this pop-up, and may do another operation without having to restart the application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code can't run. You never start `mainloop`, and you haven't defined what `organize` is.

Comment: Your example is incomplete. `organize` refers to nothing in your example. I am assuming a function exist called `organize` but we need that to test your problem.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley thanks for pointing it out to me. It's fixed, but the problem persists.

Comment: @Mike - SMT function problem fixed, but the for loop still doesn't run. Thanks

Comment: After adding the `mainloop()` at the end of your example everything works as expected. What exactly do you mean by nothing happens? According to your code all you are doing is setting the key value to `text1.get()` and it works as it should.

Comment: @Mike - SMT - I need the for loop at the bottom to run after the request values are assigned. The loop will actually start the application. Did the loop run when you tested it? It didn't in my case. When I click on the button, the value on the input box, doesn't start the loop. When I close the window, it shows on the shell, though

Comment: Add the loop inside the function. The loop as it stands now only runs at the start of the program and at that point there is nothing in the dict.

Comment: I think I got confused at what you were trying to do. I have edited my answer. Let me know if this is what you are looking for or not.

Comment: the loop you see there is a watered down version of the real one which has 3 nested loops and calls to many functions. By putting that initial loop in the function, I would have to put almost the entire program in it. As you may have noticed, the init function is intended to initialize the program by setting the user's input to the request dictionary which in turn will set all the main variables within the program. Setting the values in request to the corresponing variables through out the program has been my problem. Example:     'dir = request['dir']'     'keyword = request['key']' etc.

Comment: @Bert_AT your `init()` function does not initialize the program. The program initializes the second your start the py file. The function is only performing an action within the `mainloop()` of the Tkinter program. The application is everything in-between the `w=Tk()` and the `w.mainloop()`. I think we might be missing some context of what should be happening after the mainloop is ended.

Comment: To simply answer your comment `Did the loop run when you tested it? `. The loop can't run until you close the mainloop because you have placed the for loop after the mainloop(). I think we need more of an example of what you are trying to do or at lease more context. The code you have provided will work exactly as I expect it to so I imagine you problem is bigger than the code you have submitted here.

Comment: @Mike - SMT Yes, you're right. Is there a way to let the user interact with the interface and then pass the values to the program? Initially, I created the program in PHP, so the interface was a form in a webpage. After filling out the form, the input was then passed to the program. Now, I want to turn that web-based app into a stand alone. I think it's doable. What do you think?

Comment: @Bert_AT If you are doing a stand alone application then everything should be inside of the Tkinter instance. Between `w=Tk()` and the `w.mainloop()`. Keep in mind that Tkinter is event driven so you will need use buttons and functions to making things happen and try to avoid things like while loops. If you have a bigger code example or want to link to a github I can give you some pointers.

Comment: @Mike - SMT How can I link to github. I would really appreciate any pointers you could give to me. :)

Comment: You can paste the link in your comments or use a link in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to reread your question and your comments but I think I understand now what you are trying to do.

If you want to have a pop-up then `Toplevel()` is what you need. It will open a new window over the main window.

Here we can apply the `for` loop to add labels to the top level window.

You can do whatever you want here but as long as you do not close the `mainloop()` then you can have as many pop-ups as you need using `Toplevel()` without losing any data in the dict.

Let me know if the below helps or if it is something else you actual are trying to do:
    from tkinter import *

```
w = Tk()
request={}

def init():
        top = Toplevel(w)
        request['dir'] = text1.get()
        for key, value in request.items():
            Label(top, text=value).pack()

text1 = StringVar()
Label(text=' Folder ').grid(row=0,column=0)
Entry(textvariable = text1).grid(row=0,column=1) 
Button(text='Organize', command=init).grid(row=4,column=0) 
w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, again! I added the code where the connection should be made between the interface and the script. As you can see, the script searches a folder and then it looks for specific files, by filename and by its extension. Once found it processes each file (organizes them according to their content, creates a folder, stores the new files there) and then it should present the newly organized information to the user in case the original needs to be modified. That's the sequence. Since tkinter is event-driven, I don't know now how to present the final report. :(

Comment: @Bert_AT all that code after the `mainloop()` should be placed into a function that does all you need it to do and then open a `Toplevel()` window and display the results you need to display. I do not see any benefit from having all your extra code outside of the tkinter application.

Comment: OK. It just seems way to much code for one functions. Since that's just the beginnig of the script. The advantages I see, in case I need to expand the program are code readability and manegeability, but if there's no other way to do it, I will go with flow. Thanks a lot for all the input!!!

Comment: @Bert_AT Well you can break your code into several functions. I know my IDE (Eclipse) will tell me sometimes to reduce the `Cognitive Complexity` but I have never had actual problems with executing large functions other than mistakes I have made writing the code.

Comment: **"other than mistakes"** that's what I'm afraid of! Debugging takes longer than programming. LOL. I already started dividing the code into several functions. By the way, to report the results, would you use a Lable? I'm new at tkinter so I'm not sure what my best option would be. I need a regular size window with vertical scrollbars like a browser, because of the amount of text in the report. What would you suggest? Thanks

Comment: @Bert_AT Labels should work fine. If you are going to need a scrollbar you may need to use a canvas for scrolling over multiple widgets. You can also use a textbox or a treeview and they might work better here.